# How can I change this script to the desired number I want?

Tags: javascript, math

There is a script from PrimeDice which allows you to roll, it's provably fair.
I'm interested in the script but it rolls on a percentile die, how do I make it roll into a six-sided die?

```
var clientSeed = "Test1";
var serverSeed = 
"a72c7d6e95badadadab91d729f4eef30af2c019488bb76274290ad183";
var nonce = 1;

//----- official roll function from primedice.com

var crypto = require('crypto');

var roll = function(key, text) {  
    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key).update(text).digest('hex');    
    var index = 0;    
    var lucky = parseInt(hash.substring(index * 5, index * 5 + 5), 16);
    while (lucky >= Math.pow(10, 6)) {        
    index++;        
    lucky = parseInt(hash.substring(index * 5, index * 5 + 5), 16);        //if we reach the end of the hash, just default to highest number        
    if (index * 5 + 5 > 128) {            
        lucky = 99.99;            
        break;        
    }    
}    
lucky %= Math.pow(10, 4);    
lucky /= Math.pow(10, 2);    

return lucky;
} 

console.log(roll(serverSeed, clientSeed+'-'+nonce));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`return Math.ceil(((lucky+.01)/100)*6);`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! If you know, can you tell me the ranges?
When the roll was 96.31, it gave a 6, which is correct. So is it like if the percentile dice is 90+, or is within a certain range, it returns that?

Comment: `1/6` = `0.1666666666666667` so the ranges are just rounded to 1:`0~16.67+(-.01)`,  2:`.16.67~33.33+(-.01)`, 3:`33.33~.5+(-.01)`